# How to use html input box with extra properties?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to add the ability to use table, bold, paragraph, headings, images and bullets in a text area. How do I achieve this?

i.e. like we get input box in wordpress when we want to publish page.

or

Input box like stack over flow. Now i have options of making text bold, rich, images and many more.

I want the same kind of box.
Please tell me how can I?
Thank you

Comment: snippet of your code? or better a fiddle..

Comment: You can try CKEditor as well, take a look at http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically solved using a Javascript library. There are many javascript libraries that enable this. An example of a popular one is a javascript library named TinyMCE. They all have clear documentation on how to use them. (No need to repeat instructions here)

https://www.tinymce.com/

@ravisachaniya recommends [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)

Answer (score 0):

use tinymce it has a lot more options than you need but you can customize it to your needs https://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CKEditor, i hope solve your isseu
http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: I not you reccomend a specific product. Why do you like this product over the others?